# The method 'post' was called on null

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to login to a server and I need to post a username and password.

First of all, how can I pass the two parameters? I tried inside the body like this:

```
body: {
  "login": username, "password": password
}
```

and

```
final String param = "login=$username&password=$password";
```

I created my function like this and always got "NoSuchMethodError: The method 'post' was called on `null`.

```
  Future<http.Response> login(
      {@required String username, @required String password}) async {
    final String url = theUrl;

    final String param = "login=$username&password=$password";

    final response = await client.post(url, body: param, encoding: Encoding.getByName("UTF-8");

    return response;
  }
```

Would you mind to explain to me what this means exactly?

Full error log:

```
E/flutter ( 7161): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 7161): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'post' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 7161): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 7161): Tried calling: post("https://.../login", body: _LinkedHashMap len:2, encoding: Instance of 'Utf8Codec')
E/flutter ( 7161): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
E/flutter ( 7161): #1      ApiProvider.login (package:flutter_mvp/resources/api_provider.dart:25:35)
E/flutter ( 7161): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that the `client` variable was `null` at the time of the call.

You will have to make sure that your `client` is initialized before calling `login`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use VS code that is probably because of automatic solution. Just search in code as `get http => null;` and delete it. Instead of add
`import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;` to imports.